# Python, several callings of function containing recursions cause "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am taking the online course in Coursera "Algorithms: Design and Analysis, Part 1", and just completed the second homework. But during I was doing it, I cannot explain a phenomenon caused by python runtime error.

I am not supposed to distribute the solution code... so I just write some excerpts.

```
def quick_sort_count (arr, index, median=False):
     # SOME OPERATIONS
     ......
     # Termination
     if len(arr)==0 or len(arr)==1:
         return arr, 0
     ........
     arr[:i-1], t1 = quick_sort_count(arr[:i-1], index, median)
     arr[i:], t2 = quick_sort_count(arr[i:], index, median)
     return arr, len(arr)+t1+t2-1
```

The program should analyze a data file with 10,000 unique number and calculate how many "comparisons" are there in the quicksort. The question contains three part: using the 1st element as the pivot of comparison; using the last one; and using the "median" one.

The weird part is, I CAN have the correct answer via separately running either of the question. But I CANNOT run all three of them altogether in a function, such as

```
def main():
    # READING THE FILE
    ......
    _,result1 = quick_sort_count(arr1, 0)
    _,result2 = quick_sort_count(arr2, -1)
    _,result3 = quick_sort_count(arr3, 0, True)
```

If I did, then there will be a "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded". Something likes

```
....
arr[:i-1], t1 = quick_sort_count(arr[:i-1], index, median)
  File "/Users/c/algorithm/quick_sort.py", line 43, in quick_sort_count
arr[:i-1], t1 = quick_sort_count(arr[:i-1], index, median)
  File "/Users/c/algorithm/quick_sort.py", line 43, in quick_sort_count
arr[:i-1], t1 = quick_sort_count(arr[:i-1], index, median)
  File "/Users/c/algorithm/quick_sort.py", line 43, in quick_sort_count
arr[:i-1], t1 = quick_sort_count(arr[:i-1], index, median)
  File "/Users/c/algorithm/quick_sort.py", line 43, in quick_sort_count
arr[:i-1], t1 = quick_sort_count(arr[:i-1], index, median)
  File "/Users/c/algorithm/quick_sort.py", line 33, in quick_sort_count
arr = swap(arr, index, 0)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The "swap" is just a simple operation that changes the locations of arr[index] and arr[0], which is the requirement from the 2nd question--"use the final element as pivot element and swap it to the first element before sorting".

And if I further increase the recursion limit via

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
```

Then the 2nd and 3rd question will have wrong answers.

Can someone tell me why does this happen? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you come up with a minimal complete example that demonstrates this? It sounds like you're inadvertently keeping state somewhere, but it's hard to be sure with just the information you've given us so far.

Comment: This happens because of a bug in your quicksort algorithm. You need to properly define the recursion termination condition. Since you did not show that part in you excerpt I can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: @Ber, I add the termination in the code. It just returns when there is no elements or only one in the list.

Comment: @NPE I add some messages from terminal when I run the program. Does that help to clarify something...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you haven't posted the complete code, here's a bit of general advice on how to overcome python's recursion limit.

A generic recursive function has the following structure:

```
def foo:
    if termination-condition
        return value
    else
        new-value = some-calculations
        return foo(new-value)
```

The first step is to make your function tail-recursive, that is, eliminate the calculations in the `else` branch and bring it to the form

```
def foo:
    if termination-condition
        return value
    else
        return foo(some-calculations)
```

In a language that supports tail-recursion optimization that would be enough, in python you have to go one step further. Instead of making an immediate recursive call `return foo(...)`, let's return a "thunk", which is basically a description or a promise of what you intend to do. In python, a thunk can be written as an anonymous `lambda` function:

```
def foo:
    if termination-condition
        return value
    else
        return lambda: foo(some-calculations)
```

Of course, you'll need another intermediate function that would consume values returned from `foo` and if a thunk is given, carries it out until a terminal (non-function) value is returned:

```
def foo-interface:
    # get a thunk or a terminal
    t = foo()  
    # while it's a thunk...
    while callable(t):
        t = t() # ...carry it out
    # return the terminal
    return t
```

### Example

Let's have the following naive implementation  of factorial, which fails on large arguments:

```
def fac(n):
    return 1 if n < 2 else n * fac(n - 1)

> fac(3000)
> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Convert it to tail-recursive...

```
def f(n, acc=1):
    return acc if n < 2 else f(n - 1, acc * n)
```

...apply the thunk transformation...

```
def f(n, acc):
    return acc if n < 2 else lambda: f(n - 1, acc * n)
```

...and wrap it in an interface function (consumer)...

```
def fac(n):

    def f(n, acc):
        return acc if n < 2 else lambda: f(n - 1, acc * n)

    t = f(n, 1)
    while callable(t):
        t = t()
    return t
```

It works!

```
> fac(3000)
> 41493596034....
```

This technique is called "trampolining". Don't know if this is helpful in your particular case (hence CW), but I guess this is something good to know about (and to impress your prof, by chance)).

### Decorator

This kind of tail recursion can be written as a decorator. A nice explanation using classes instead of `lambda` is given [here](http://web.mit.edu/kmill/www/programming/tailcall.html).

Comment: As quitsort has two recursion at each level it cannot be converted to tail recursion.

Comment: The trampoline can be written as a function decorator, and reused for all tail recursive functions.

Comment: @Ber: thanks for your comments, as this post is CW, feel free to improve it.

Comment: Thanks @thg435 :) Though the answer is not specific for my question, it does give me some insights about how to manage recursive calls in python.